# Apache 2 subdomain?

Tags: apache

I've been looking for articles pertaining to how to do this, but I'm finding any detailed and straight forward instructions. I do know there's a lot of information pertaining to this, but maybe I'm just not looking for the right things.

In the control panel for my domain name, I added `blog.domain.com` to go to my webserver's IP address. However, within Apache's configuration, I'd like to be able to direct `blog.domain.com` to a certain folder.

What file do I need to modify and what do I need to add to it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for `NameVirtualHost`. I use it all the time & it works great!

It’s not clear what OS you are using, but in general you need to first activate `NameVirtualHost` for the port you want.  I will assume you will use port 80, so find this line in your Apache config & set as so:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

Make sure your Apache config is set to list to port 80. Which should be the case, but adding here for reference:

```
Listen 80
```

Then for your subdomain, here is where the magic happens.  Again, I am just doing the basics so adjust to whatever your server settings are:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName blog.domain.com
  ServerAlias blog.domain.com

  DocumentRoot /var/www/blog.domain.com

</VirtualHost>
```

The key is the `ServerName` and the wildcard on `VirtualHost`. That basically states, “Okay, we are using `NameVirtualHost` on port 80, this config is for the server name `blog.domain.com` so I will pay attention to all options in this config & apply them only to `blog.domain.com`. And the `DocumentRoot` should be what I indicate in this config.”

**EDIT:** Adding additional advice based on the original posters comment below.

First, do not edit `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` in any way. Instead create a new config file just for your new subdomain. This makes it easier to manage. I will assume you need to run `sudo` and edit with `nano` for my examples:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/blog.domain.com.conf
```

And add the `VirtualHost` stuff I have above to that new `blog.domain.com.conf` file. Of course make sure your `VirtualHost` directives match what you want; mine is only a bare example.

Now if that’s done, you need to create a symbolic link from `sites-available` to `sites-enabled` like so:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/blog.domain.com.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/blog.domain.com.conf
```

Okay, that’s all done?  Since it seems like you have a similar Apache2 config layout like the Ubuntu 12.04 servers I have worked on, go in this file to see if `NameVirtualHost` is set:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/ports.conf
```

You should see two lines like so:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 80
```

Okay, all set? Now, restart Apache & you should be set!

If you want to test, create a test file in your document root for the subdomain that has this line in it; I am assuming you can use PHP:

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
?>
```

If all works, it should echo back the subdomain of the host that directory is setup for: `blog.domain.com`

Comment: Thanks so much Jake! Just to make sure I'm in the right file, are we talking about /etc/apache2/sites-available/default?

Also, since there's already a <VirtualHost> section, do I need to add an additional one containing that information?

Comment: Thanks SO much man. One more quick question. As far as my domain name settings, what do I need to add/modify? Like, currently, I just have it configured to where blog.domainname.com would go to my VPS's IP address, and I figured perhaps the config on apache would handle the rest. My perception of this is more than likely wrong though.

Comment: Hmm, gotcha. I think I may still be missing something as far as the configs may go though. So my domain name settings are configured to route blog.domain.com to my VPS's IP address, and I've made those changes above, but when I go to blog.mydomain.com, it still goes to the root web server's directory. Also made sure I restarted Apache too. Hmmm :\

Comment: Hmm. here's a copy of my default file inside of the sites-available directory, https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2526790/apache2/default.txt. Here's the ports.conf: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2526790/apache2/ports.txt

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40895/discussion-between-lewlsauce-and-jakegould)